# Which Loader on LangChain is suitable for uploading video directly from your computer for processing?

Tags: video, langchain, py-langchain

I'm trying to build a program that transcribes a downloaded video on my computer. The app is built using LangChain. I see a lot of tutorials for how I can transcribe YouTube videos in LangChain using their YouTubeLoader + the WhisperParser, but I'm not sure how I can load a video from my computer instead of using the YouTubeLoader.

I also tried the UnstructuredFileLoader, but that doesn't seem to process mp3/mp4 either.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't seen some specific loaders In LangChain for locally saved video clips, I suggest using additional Python libraries, such as denoiser, moviepy to extract text from video clips, then save those texts into vector storages, that are available in LangChain and after that - use the build in LangChain retrievers. For example, you can use the next article as a baseline for extracting text from videos: [How to Convert Speech to Text in Python](https://thepythoncode.com/article/using-speech-recognition-to-convert-speech-to-text-python)